# Disapearing menu after first element lose hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all I'm not good at JavaScript, usually I'm using "ready to go" frameworks. This time I had to do something on my own.
Website: http://nordica.optimo365.pl 
Sorry, it's in Polish, so when you "hover" on "PIŁKA NOŻNA" -> "Buty Piłkarskie" everything is fine, but when you go down to "Piłki" the menu is disapearing.
I'm guessing when "Buty Piłkarskie" lose "hover", menu is shrinking and mouse is outside the menu. Please tell me how to fix this?

```
<ul class="nav">
   {% for gn in groupNodes %}
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ gn.Url }}" data-id="{{ gn.Id }}" class="nav-link" id="nav-item_{{ gn.Name |Remove:' ' }}">
              {{gn.Name}}
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        {% for gnn in gn.Nodes %}
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link sub-link" data-id="{{ gnn.Id }}" href="{{ gnn.Url }}">{{ gnn.Name }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header .primary-nav .categories-menu-container > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:-35px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0.2px 0px #424242;
  }
}
```

First 2 nodes ("PIŁKA NOŻNA" -> "Buty Piłkarskie") are just in Liquid loop, if you want to go deeper, you have to use asynchronous JS

```
        (function () {
    $(function () {
        $('header .primary-nav .categories-menu-container > ul > li > ul a').hover(
function () {
    var t = $(this), gId = ('' + t.data('id')).split(',')[1];
    if (gId && t.find('ol').length == 0) {
        $.get(null, { __action: 'Get/Groups', groupId: gId, languageId: __lngId }, function (d) {

            var obj = d.action.Object;
            if (obj.length) {
                var ol = $('<ol class="nav"></ol>');
                t.append(ol);
                $.each(obj, function (i, el) {
                    var a = $('<a class="nav-link sub-sub-link"></a>').attr('href', el.Url).text(el.Title);
                    ol.append(a);
                    a.wrap('<li class="nav-item"></li>')
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else t.find('ol').show();
},
function () {
    $(this).find('ol').hide();
}
);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example - either in a snippet in the question or in a JS fiddle?

Comment: @NisargShah Has he not done that already in the question?

Comment: You can use the "example" on original website. It's just there, why I need to do same again in fiddle?

Comment: @TronComputers : have you tried the solution i provided in ans below. i have cheched that on your site itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused due to `margin-bottom` applied to the `<li>` elements inside the "PIŁKA NOŻNA" tab as shown below.

```
header .primary-nav .categories-menu-container > ul > li > ul > li {
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: small;
    margin-bottom: 11px; <-- This results in removing the hover effect
}
```

If you inspect the "Buty Piłkarskie" `<li>` and remove the `margin-bottom: 11px;` it will work as expected.

Hope this help you.

Comment: OMG! That's it but... If you refresh the page at first time it's still not working but when you do this again it's fine.

Comment: You have to update the css for that. This code is present in your main.css. just search there and remove it. It will work

Comment: This was the main cause. However we have to check if there are any other css which is causing it at first time now

Comment: Currently it is main.css...if you cannot change the main.css then you can write the jquery hover enent code for removing and adding margin-top on hovering and coming out.

Comment: But I changed it 37 mins ago

Comment: `margin-bottom: 11px;` issue was in main.css...The issue which you are getting on 1st time is not neccasary in main.css. it might also be in your HTML structure or the way you are handling the hover event

Comment: 2nd issue is intermittent. Sometimes i get the hover correct for the first time and also sometimes i am able to see repeated sub-menus 2-3 times.i don't thing it it related to the code you removed from main.css

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when you move your cursor from "Buty Piłkarskie", hover event of the `li` element is getting removed. Thus it is hiding inner elements and you second menu moving upward so again you are losing hover event of your main menu.

As much as I know you need to either trigger Main menu event on click or you need to add the delay of a second thus user can move to next menu.

Comment: I can't do this on click because customers should be able to select this category

Comment: You can add delay before hiding dropdown.